# UIViewPropertyAnimator crashes on dealloc after calling finishAnimation(at:)

Tags: ios, uikit

When using UIViewPropertyAnimator and calling `finishAnimation(at:)` after `stopAnimation(false)`:

You either get a crash log of:

```
- [UIViewPropertyAnimator dealloc]
```

Or if you catch the assertion in a debugger (by setting an breakpoint for Objective-C exceptions)

**Assertion failure in -[UIViewPropertyAnimator finishAnimationAtPosition:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3900.12.16/UIViewPropertyAnimator.m:1981**

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'finishAnimationAtPosition: should only be called on a stopped animator!'**

If you manage to catch the assertion, (the crash log isn't that helpful unless you catch those at release runtime as well), you will see that it complains about `finishAnimation` being called on a non-stopped animator.

Yet my code shows the animator always being stopped before finishAnimation is called.

```
animator.stopAnimation(false)
animator.finishAnimation(at: .start)
```

What could be causing this crash, the state should always be stopped after calling `stopAnimation`?

Comment: It seems to me this is a bug in `UIViewPropertyAnimator`'s implementation. The documentation states clearly that _"if you specify false for the withoutFinishing parameter, you can subsequently call the finishAnimation(at:) method to perform the animator’s final actions"_.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this happened for me was a timing issue with completion blocks:

It means that `UIViewPropertyAnimator.state` (`UIViewAnimatingState`) is in an invalid state. Since this is just an Objective C enum it can have any raw value beyond what is defined in the cases. In the case of my crash the value was `5`.

I was doing a bunch of chained animations that referenced each other and had something like this:

```
animator.addCompletion({ _ in
    // Here I called a piece of code that eventually referenced this animator
    // and attempted to call `stopAnimation(false)` and `finishAnimation(at:)` 
    // on it causing the crash.
    //
    // You will notice if you examine the `state` of the animator here, it will have 
    // an invalid `rawValue` of 5, at least up to iOS 13.2, as this is an implementation detail.
})
```

**The solution is to not attempt any operations on the animator until the completion block is finished executing.**

If you can not avoid it, a workaround that works with current UIKit implementations is to `DispatchQueue.main.async` out of that completion block which will allow it to finish. Of course, this is not a guarantee that the state will be valid inside of that async in future versions of iOS.

On Swift, to debug this you can use the following extension:

```
extension UIViewAnimatingState: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var isValid: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .inactive, .active, .stopped:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .inactive:
            return "inactive"
        case .active:
            return "active"
        case .stopped:
            return "stopped"
        default:
            return "\(rawValue)"
        }
    }

    public var debugDescription: String {
        return description
    }
}
```

Therefore when you call `stopAnimation(false)` and `finishAnimation(at:)` you can at least avoid a crash and alert yourself to a possible logical issue with your animators:

```
// This is for debugging, the code below should be safe even if isValid is false
assert(animator.state.isValid, "animator state is not valid")

animator.stopAnimation(false)

if animator.state == .stopped {
    // This call is the one that can assert and crash the app
    animator.finishAnimation(at: .start)
}
```

Comment: It's great that you solved it, but this answer in no way grows out of anything you said in the question. The question as it stands is inadequate and unsolvable.

Comment: I've updated the question to more properly reflect why this crash is hard to debug and puzzling at first. Since I found the solution before I truly had a proper question it was formed that way. For those that face this issue in the future I think this post will be helpful, I'd appreciate if you update your vote. Thank you.